# Approximation of sum of products of exponentials

Tags: calculus

i have the following expression:

$\rho(t)=\sum\limits_{i}\mathrm{e}^{2/\tau(-t+t_i-a_i/2)}\sigma(t-t_i)$

where $a_i$ is a evenly distributed random number between 0 and a positve value, say $a$. Under what assumptions can I approximate this expression such that I somehow can take the $a_i$ out of the sum and replace it with it's mean or some other arithmetic measure?

Comment: Assume that $a_i$ is independent of $a_j$ for $i \neq j$, perhaps?  (i.e., pairwise independence assumption)

Comment: yes, that is indeed true. But does that mean i can take it out of the sum?

Comment: i would like to write something like this:
$\rho(t)=\sum\limits_{i}\mathrm{e}^{2/\tau(-t+t_i-a_i/2)}\sigma(t-t_i) \approx \sum\limits_{i}\mathrm{e}^{2/\tau(-t+t_i-a/4)}\sigma(t-t_i)$ where $\frac{a}{2}$ is the mean of all $a_i$, but i don't know to what extend this is a valid approximation